# Can't Access Destructuring Assignment from Complex Object

Tags: coffeescript, destructuring

Given the input value:

```
input = 
    name:'Foo'
    id:'d4cbd9ed-fabc-11e6-83e6-307bd8cc75e3'
    ref:5
    addtData:'d4cbd9ed-fabc-11e6-83e6-307bd8cc75e3'
    data:'bar'
```

When I try to destructure the input via a function like this:

```
simplify: (input)->
    { name, ref, id } = input
```

...the return value is still the full input or a copy of the input.

Am I missing something simple here?  How can I access the destructured value.  If you can't access the value via a return, it seems that destructuring has little value outside of locally scoped values.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't necessarily an advantage, the only way I was able to transpile and get the correct answer was to assign the destructure values to the local scope using `@` (aka `this`).

```
input = 
    name:'foo'
    data:'bar'
    id: 12314
    key:'children'
    ref:1

f = (input)->
    { @name, @id } = input

r = {}
f.call(r, input)
console.log r # Object {name: "foo", id: 12314}
```

working example - [link](http://coffeescript.org/#try:input%20%3D%20%0A%09name%3A'foo'%0A%09data%3A'bar'%0A%09id%3A%2012314%0A%09key%3A'children'%0A%09ref%3A1%0A%0Af%20%3D%20(input)-%3E%0A%09%7B%20%40name%2C%20%40id%20%7D%20%3D%20input%0A%0Ar%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Af.call(r%2C%20input)%0Aconsole.log%20r)

If someone has a better way to approach this, please add an answer so I can select it as this doesn't seem like the best way.